# How to print "hello world" to console

Tags: python, logging, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP server set up that receives SOAP messages from a foreign server. I want to be able to process these messages. Thanks to these two lines of code in my server, I am able to see the messages in my console:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Is there anyway I can convert this message to a string and then to an object instance?
I understand this isn't very pythonic and the best way would be to set up a WSDL that matches the server WSDL but this is beyond my programming capabilities, and at the moment there isn't a WSDL parser library I can use either.

This a sample message that I want to handle from the foreign server displayed in my console.

```
<Item xsi:type="Dp_Data">
    <UCPTname>Net/MB485/MAIN POWER/Fb/PowerSum</UCPTname>
    <UCPTlastUpdate>2014-04-04T13:34:17.441-04:00</UCPTlastUpdate>
    <UCPTformatDescription>#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI</UCPTformatDescription>
    <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI">9330.949</UCPTvalue>
    <UCPTpointStatus>AL_OFFLINE</UCPTpointStatus>
    <UCPTpriority>255</UCPTpriority>
    <UCPTpropagate>0</UCPTpropagate>
</Item>
```

I want to convert this message to a string and then possibly an object instance where item would have attributes UCPTname, UCPTlastUpdate, UCPTvalue etc.

Please respond.

This is the full message:

```
DEBUG:spyne.protocol.xml:[1;32mMethod request string:[0m                     {http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/}Write
DEBUG:spyne.protocol.xml:<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <p:messageProperties xmlns:p="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
      <p:UCPTtimeStamp>2014-04-04T15:38:03.641-04:00</p:UCPTtimeStamp>
      <p:UCPTuniqueId>03000029B512</p:UCPTuniqueId>
      <p:UCPTipAddress>10.217.247.36</p:UCPTipAddress>
      <p:UCPTport>80</p:UCPTport>
      <p:UCPTlastUpdate>2014-04-04T19:38:03Z</p:UCPTlastUpdate>
    </p:messageProperties>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <Write xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
      <iLonItem><Item xsi:type="Dp_Data">
    <UCPTname>Net/MB485/MAIN POWER/Fb/PowerSum</UCPTname>
    <UCPTlastUpdate>2014-04-04T15:37:33.891-04:00</UCPTlastUpdate>
    <UCPTformatDescription>#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI</UCPTformatDescription>
    <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI">95860.3</UCPTvalue>
    <UCPTpointStatus>AL_NO_CONDITION</UCPTpointStatus>
    <UCPTpriority>255</UCPTpriority>
    <UCPTpropagate>1</UCPTpropagate>
</Item>
</iLonItem>
    </Write>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: Is that all you are receiving? No envelope or anything else?

Comment: I receive the full SOAP response. The message I attached is in the SOAP body.

Comment: Could you post all of it? (at least envelope and body tags?) I'd like to have a full example

Comment: I posted it all for you! :)

Comment: Woops... it came a bit late... Let me know if your answer is ok. I'll try to make it better if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [SoapPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SOAPpy/0.12.5) (not Soapy, be careful) and take a look of the possible types that SOAP defines ([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/)).

Then you can parse your message like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869427/how-to-print-hello-world-to-console
import SOAPpy
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

item_str='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
         <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \
            xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" \
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\
            <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\
                <Item xsi:type="Dp_Data">\
                    <UCPTname>Net/MB485/MAIN POWER/Fb/PowerSum</UCPTname>\
                    <UCPTlastUpdate>2014-04-04T13:34:17.441-04:00</UCPTlastUpdate>\
                    <UCPTformatDescription>#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI</UCPTformatDescription>\
                    <UCPTvalue LonFormat="#0000000000000000[0].SNVT_power_f#SI">9330.949</UCPTvalue>\
                    <UCPTpointStatus>AL_OFFLINE</UCPTpointStatus>\
                    <UCPTpriority>255</UCPTpriority>\
                    <UCPTpropagate>0</UCPTpropagate>\
                </Item>\
            </soap:Body>\
        </soap:Envelope>'
expected = { 'Item': {
    'UCPTname': (SOAPpy.NS.XSD, "string"),
    'UCPTlastUpdate': (SOAPpy.NS.XSD, "dateTime"),
    'UCPTpriority': (SOAPpy.NS.XSD, "unsignedByte"),
    'UCPTpropagate': (SOAPpy.NS.XSD, "boolean"),
}}


item = SOAPpy.parseSOAPRPC(item_str, rules=expected)
logging.debug("Name: %s" % item['UCPTname'])
logging.debug("Last update: %s" % (item['UCPTlastUpdate'],))
logging.debug("Priority: %s" % item['UCPTpriority'])
logging.debug("Should this be propagated? %s" % ('Yeep' if item['UCPTpropagate'] else 'Nopes'))
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I think I have to place this in a while loop? Because I'm not sure how logging works. It basically logs all errors but in order to get the rest of the code to run everytime an error is logged what would I do?

Comment: Very insightful btw. Also how would I convert my message to item_str? I'm very new to how web servers work.

Comment: You can wrap that code in an infinite loop, although SoapPy should be able to connect to the server that is sending you that data (take a look to https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy/blob/develop/docs/GettingStarted.txt and to the 'tests' directory of SoapPy: https://github.com/kiorky/SOAPpy/tree/develop/tests)